# Data import in Pyomo from csv or xlsx

Tags: load, data-import, pyomo

I have an abstract model in Pyomo which I need to run a couple of times with changing data which is why I'd like to have some easy data import from csv or xls. I tried the DataPortal as well as directly writing a data file but don't succeed and would appreciate your help!!

DataPortal

I am well aware of the site https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/examples/doc/pyomobook/attic/ref-dataportal/dataportal_tab.py and tried to just implement it accordingly - without success :/

I try to import 'timespan' as a set. I have a column called 'timespan' in the csv/xls file which goes from 0 to 23.

Import from xlsx:

```
data = DataPortal()
data.load(filename='Operational_Data.xlsx', range='timespan', set=dispatch.timespan)
data.load(filename='Operational_Data.xlsx', range=('D2:D49'), param='elload', index=dispatch.timespan)
instance = dispatch.create_instance(data)
```

Neither of both range options (column title and excel range) work, timespan stays empty.
Import from csv:

```
data.load(filename='Operational_Data.csv', set='timespan')
```

Importing from csv only imports tuples such that it includes neighbouring columns into 'timespan' which, however, has only one dimension.

Directly via data.dat file:

```
load Operational_Data.csv using=csv format=set : timespan=[timespan];
```

Throws

```
OSError: Must specify at least one set or parameter name that will be loaded.
```

How can I import data for my abstract pyomo model?

Thanks!
Malo

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer! I tried a couple of objects like dataframes but was not lucky... I must admit that I haven't tried openpyxl yet but finally succeeded by writing a function which writes my data from a csv to an AMPL format-like file (.dat). Not very elegant but it works :)

Answer (score -1):

Try using a different library like openpyxl to open files, then load them into pyomo objects

Comment: "load them into pyomo objects" - what does that look like, code-wise? The original author included code that you could have used to explain how to do it. This is a low effort answer